# Paypal checkout.js - Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null

Tags: javascript, paypal, express-checkout

My Paypal integration is using the checkout.js library. I get the following error in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
at setup (index.js:265)
```

Line 265 looks like

```
var button = document.getElementById('buttonContainer').querySelector('button');
```

My script is as follows and succesfully loads the Paypal checkout button. Due to the javascript error, the button can't be clicked.

```
<div id="paypal-button"></div>

<script>
    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment

        payment: function(resolve, reject) {

            var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = /paypal/create';

            paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL)
                .then(function(data) { resolve(data.paymentID); })
                .catch(function(err) { reject(err); });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data) {

            var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = /paypal/execute';

            paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL,
                { paymentID: data.paymentID, payerID: data.payerID })
                .then(function(data) {
                    var orderNumber = data.paymentCart;
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    alert('There was an error executing the payment, please try again');
                });
            }
    }, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

The integration seemed to be working fine yesterday as well.

Comment: is there an element with id="buttonContainer" in the DOM?

Comment: Did you check if there is an Element with the ID: buttonContainer?

Comment: No there isn't. Its not mentioned in the Paypal documentation. The 2nd parameter of paypal.Button.render() is the container for the pay button which isn't the issue as that is being rendered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What the error says is that:
document.getElementById('buttonContainer') is null.

In other words, we did not find any element whose id is buttonContainer.
Therefore, it fails to perform a querySelector inside it.

With the pieces of code shared, we cannot really help as we cannot see whether you have defined the button or not and whether it's accessible at the time of loading this.

My best guess, based on experience, is that the button may load dynamically at a later stage and it's not ready at the moment you try to retrieve it.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more explicit in my question. I understand the Javascript error and why its occurring. My issue is that the missing element isn't mentioned in the [Paypal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-integration/) (assuming Paypal injects it?) and that this exact code was working yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The bug must have been caused by an update to the Paypal library as the error no longer occurs.